# Test whether Time(7) datatype value is 00:00:00.0000000 in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table called 'Messages' in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database. One of the columns in this table is `TimeSent` of `time(7)` type.

Sometimes this column value is `00:00:00.0000000` for a few rows in the table as shown in screenshot below.

My question is: how would I write a query to get all rows that have a zero time (not null) in them for column `TimeSent`? The query below that I tried does not work.

```
SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE TimeSent = 0
```

[image: TimeSent value of 00:00:00.0000000]

**UPDATE 1:**

While the answer from marc_s is the accepted answer, I also found another way of checking for zero time in SQL Server 2008 R2 as in code below.

```
DECLARE @zeroTime AS time(7);
SET @zeroTime = CAST('20140101' AS time(7));
SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE TimeSent = @zeroTime;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT * 
FROM Messages 
WHERE TimeSent = '00:00:00.0000000'
```

Does that work?

Comment: Yes that works. Also I found, the 0 string need not be an exact match as long as at least two time parts are specified. So "where TimeSent = '00:00' " also works, and so does "where TimeSent = '0:0' " BUT "where TimeSent ='0' " does not work . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *  from Messages
WHERE timesent = TIMEFROMPARTS  (0,0,0,0,0)
```

Comment: `TIMEFROMPARTS` is a new feature in SQL Server **2012** and thus not available to the OP who's on 2008 R2 ....